# TinyMCE React cursor back to start after typing a key

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE-React and when I type my text in the TinyMCE Editor with an initial value, the cursor constantly returns at the start of the text...

> `import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";`
>
> ```
>   const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
>     title: "",
>     text: "",
>   });
>
>
> if (post) {
>   setFormData((formData) => ({
>     ...formData,
>     title: post.title,
>     text: post.text,
>   }));
> }
> ```
>
> `const { title, text } = formData;`

My function :

> ```
> const textChange = (e) => {
> setFormData({ ...formData.text, text: e });   };
> ```

My Editor :

> ```
>     <Editor
>       name='text'
>       initialValue={text}
>       onEditorChange={(e) => textChange(e)}
>     />
> ```

I think it's because of the "setFormData" but I don't know how can I edit the text with a regular cursor which stays at the end of the text...

Comment: You may have more luck getting this answered if you can create a working minimal example as testing this code is difficult in it's current state. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 20):

Late answer, but here's the fix: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react/issues/267.

Change `initialValue={text}` to `value={text}`.

This is the right setup for using the TinyMCE React component as a "controlled" component: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#usingthetinymcereactcomponentasacontrolledcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I had two separate variables for initial value and for the editor on change.
Ref: https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with **newValue** props

```
<Editor
      apiKey="jeiltvbooyoyr3fe3xt511l45gkbcj9wrq1pj5hhpfrsqmua"
      onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
      newValue={content}
      onChange={() => setContent(editorRef.current.getContent())}
      automatic_uploads={false}
      init={{
        height: 500,
        menubar: true,
        branding: false,
        images_upload_url: `${API_BASE_URL}/file/storage/upload`,
        plugins: [
          "advlist",
          "autolink",
          "lists",
          "link",
          "image",
          "charmap",
          "preview",
          "anchor",
          "searchreplace",
          "visualblocks",
          "code",
          "fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime",
          "media",
          "table",
          "code",
          "help",
          "wordcount",
        ],
        toolbar:
          "undo redo | blocks | " +
          "bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
          "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
          "removeformat | help",
        content_style:
          "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is you need to set `onInit` function when Tinymce load then this function hits and value will load in `initialValue` which is starting value when Tinymce loaded.

```tsx
interface ITinyMCE {
 value: string
  setValue: (val: any) => void
}

export default function TinyMCE({ value, setValue }: ITinyMCE) {
  const [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState<string>('')

  return (
    <Editor
      apiKey='api-key'
      onInit={(evt, editor) => {
        setInitialValue(value)
      }}
      initialValue={initialValue}
      value={value}
      init={{
        height: 500,
        plugins: [
          "advlist",
          "autolink",
          "lists",
          "link",
          "image",
          "charmap",
          "preview",
          "anchor",
          "searchreplace",
          "visualblocks",
          "code",
          "fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime",
          "media",
          "table",
          "code",
          "help",
          "wordcount",
        ],
        toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code preview",
        images_upload_url: "http://localhost:3001/upload_article_images",
        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_reuse_filename: true,
        images_upload_handler: handleImageUpload
      }}
      onEditorChange={(content) => {
        setValue(content)
      }}
    />
  )
}
```